# ruby koan sandwich line count

Tags: ruby, block

I was working through the about_sandwich_code example in the Ruby Koans example, completed code link here [about_sandwich_code.rb](https://github.com/javierjulio/ruby-koans-completed/blob/master/about_sandwich_code.rb) for reference. The following is the relevant reference code for easy reference.

```
  def count_lines(file_name)
    file = open(file_name)
    count = 0
    while file.gets
      count += 1
    end
    count
  ensure
    file.close if file
  end

  def test_counting_lines
    assert_equal 4, count_lines("example_file.txt")
  end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------

  def find_line(file_name)
    file = open(file_name)
    while line = file.gets
      return line if line.match(/e/)
    end
  ensure
    file.close if file
  end

  def test_finding_lines
    assert_equal "test\n", find_line("example_file.txt")
  end

  def file_sandwich(file_name)
    file = open(file_name)
    yield(file)
  ensure
    file.close if file
  end
```

In my attempt at writing `find_line2` method I tried the following code which compiled.

```
    def find_line2(file_name)
     file_sandwich(file_name) do |file|
      while file.gets
        return file.gets if file.gets.match(/e/)
      end
     end
    end

  def test_finding_lines2
    assert_equal "test\n", find_line2("example_file.txt")
  end
```

For reference, [example_file.txt](https://github.com/javierjulio/ruby-koans-completed/blob/master/example_file.txt).

However, the koans returned the following in the terminal window: `Expected "test\n" to equal nil`

This raised my awareness as the penultimate koan code/test for the analogous finding lines  function pre-sandwich code solved that koan.

```
  def test_finding_lines
    assert_equal "test\n", find_line("example_file.txt")
  end
```

As I tried different options, I realized that the following `find_line2` implementation

```
def find_line2(file_name)
file_sandwich(file_name) do |file|
  while line = file.gets
    return line if line.match(/e/)
  end
end
```

When run with

```
  def test_finding_lines2
    assert_equal "test\n", find_line2("example_file.txt")
  end
```

resolves the koan rather than tell me that the test should equal nil as the prior screenshot shows. So what this amounts to, as I understand in this moment is that my first implementation somehow changes what the koan program expects as the check, which sort of baffles me. I think it means my attempt somehow broke the koan, but I'm not sure why. Actually, after running `file_sandwich` and my first implementation of `find_line2` I see the call `find_line2("example_file.txt")` to return `nil`, so for some reason `file.gets` acts differently than using `line` after the `line = file.gets` in the `while` statement.

Can someone explain why my first implementation and the answer don't equal? I believe that the answer lies in a more clear understanding of blocks?

Comment: In `find_line2`, `while file.gets; return file.gets; if file.gets.match(/e/); end` reads three successive lines, provided there are three lines left in the file.  If there are one or two lines left, you'll try to read beyond the end of the file, so an exception will be raised.  In any event you want `if line = file.gets...` and then just refer to `line`.

Comment: Maybe try to express your question with more words and less code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "reads three successive lines, … so an exception will be raised," -Cary Swoveland, perhaps you can explain more. I guess in the end, I'm just unsure the difference between using `line = file.gets` in while conditional statement vs. just `file.gets`

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_line2(file_name)

 file_sandwich(file_name) do |file|

  while file.gets #gets the next line in the file

    if file.gets.match(/e/) #gets the next line and checks for a match
      return file.gets #gets the next line and returns it. 
    end #restructured for clarity 
  end
 end
end
```

So with the example file: `This\nis\na\ntest` you code gets `This\n`, gets `is\n` and checks it `(fail)`. On the next iteration, your code gets `a\n`, gets `test\n` and checks it `(true)`, then gets the next line `(nil)` and returns it.